# Aptanas Build In PHP vs Eclipse PHP

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana

I've been back and forth through various IDEs (Netbeans, PHPStorm, even VIM) and am now back at a stable and well configured Aptana Studio - mainly for the great FTP Support and the overall feel.

However, I've tasted the sweet blood of amazing code completion for PHP on Storm and even Netbeans and have the feel that Aptana lacks a bit of the advanced code completion features  (e.g. when a custom class method returns an instance of another custom class, it's a first class citizen in php storm with full support for cc).

Now I wonder if the Eclipse PHP Tools are better than the ones with Aptana. Since I had some problems with mixing plugins in Aptana lately, I want to hear some opinions before I go that road:

1. Is the Eclipse PHP better than Aptanas PHPs?
2. What are the main differences?
3. Are there any cool PHP (or general webdev tools) that may close that gap for eclipse?

I've found only outdated links, so I'd be interested in some up-to-date insights.

Answer (score 1):

I love Aptana and its CSS/JS features, but the php code completition is not compareable to the features of eclipse pdt or netbeans. Because of that: Yes, Eclipse PHP is better than aptana php. To name only one missing feature in aptana: phpdoc support and autocompletition for that.

I would mix up aptana + pdt, but that makes more problems for me, than in solves :(